# Styling AngularJS ui-router navigation tabs

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am rewriting an app using AngularJS. The tabs have a certain styling that I don't want to change. But upon using ui-router, specifically replacing "href" with "ui-sref", the look of navigation tabs gets messed up because I think the JavaScript and CSS is defined for "href".

I tried replacing all instances of href with ui-sref but that didn't work.

I've looked into Bootstrap but I need to render new pages upon clicking the tabs, not display data already on the page but hidden. Like Bootstrap does.

Can someone please suggest me what to do? How to modify the current styling or maybe suggest some other css template that I can use only for the navigation tabs? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should add more tags to this, this sounds more like its a CSS issue rather than an Angular issue.  Its possible the CSS statements are `a[href] { ... }` since the look has changed when you removed the `href` attribute.

Comment: Added CSS. Thanks. I checked the entire CSS file but it doesn't have any mention of href anywhere. The JavaScript file has the part where all the functionality is defined but it is minified and impossible for me to understand.

Comment: What was the original application using? jQuery? Maybe the original was adding classes on the fly with `$[element].addClass('myclass')` you may want to look for something like that.

Comment: Yes it was using jQuery. Thanks. I'll look into it.

Comment: "I think the JavaScript and CSS is defined for 'href'" -- you can certainly determine if this is true (for the css at least) by using your browsers built-in inspector.  You can learn a lot by inspecting different elements.